# Partially protect API endpoint with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

Based on the user login status, I want to serve different results from the SAME api endpoint.

The usecase is having articles served from the same api endpoints.
So some articles meant to be public, while some private.
There are also special pages, where a list of articles can be queried.

Example:
api/articles/special/all

This API should return all pages currently in the database. 
But it should also filter out private results, if the user is not logged in.

With Passport.js I can only protect the whole API endpoint, eg:

```
router.get('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.index);
```

While I would like to call the auth.isAuthenticated() method from within the actual function, eg:

```
// Get list of articles
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Article.find(function (err, articles) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    var titles = [];
    var loggedIn = false;
    if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {loggedIn = true;} // NOT WORKING
    for (var i = 0; i<articles.length; ++i) {
      if (articles[i].role === 'loggedIn' && loggedIn) {
          titles.push(articles[i].name);
      } else if(articles[i].role !== 'loggedIn') {
        titles.push(articles[i].name);
      }
    }
    return res.json(200, titles);
  });
};
```

Any idea, how to use Passport.js from within the controller, and not protecting the whole API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to accomplish this with passport.js, but if you're using something like [Stormpath](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/index.html), this is quite easy to accomplish out of the box.

Once you've initialized / configured the express-stormpath middleware, it will automatically attempt to authenticate ANY user *without* making you explicitly use middleware.

So for instance, you could say:

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();

app.use(stormpath.init(app));

app.get('/myapi', function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    res.json({ status: 'YOU ARE LOGGED IN: ' + req.user.email });
  } else {
    res.json({ status: 'YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN!' });
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Because Stormpath stores your users for you, if you're using the express-stormpath library this means that it will try to authenticate users either via a web session (in the browser), or a user's API keys (which Stormpath also stores).

This is why it's pretty simple to work, as the middleware will inspect the incoming HTTP headers and authenticate a user properly with either Basic Auth or OAuth2 =)